how Limit length digit of all type characters in regex with vb.net
I'm Trying to Limit length of all type characters in regex with vb.net
I want to validate and for Name,NotEmpty,Number,DecimalI managed to do it but for DIGIT10,DIGIT15,DIGIT20,DIGIT25I can't do it yet .
whether this possibility can be for all characters either strings or numbers or others?
So I want to limit the length of all characters with a minimum of 1 digit and the length of the digit must not exceed the digit that has been set, for example DiGiT10 then the length of the character is at least 1 digit and the maximum is 10 digits means that digits 1-10 are allowed
Please Guide me
Thanks
Public Property ValidationType As ValidationTypes
            Get
                Return Me._validationType
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As ValidationTypes)
                Me._validationType = value
                Select Case value
                    Case ValidationTypes.None
                        Me.Regex = Nothing
                        Return
                    Case ValidationTypes.Name
                        Me.Regex = "^[a-z ,.'-]+$"
                        Return
 Case ValidationTypes.NotEmpty
                        Me.Regex = "(.|\s)*\S(.|\s)*"
                        Return
                    Case ValidationTypes.Number
                        Me.Regex = "^\d+$"
                        Return
                    Case ValidationTypes.Decimal
                        Me.Regex = "^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$"
                        Return
                        Return
                    Case ValidationTypes.DIGIT10
                        Me.Regex = "^\d{1,10}"
                        Return
                    Case ValidationTypes.DIGIT15
                        Me.Regex = ""
                        Return
                    Case ValidationTypes.DIGIT20
                        Me.Regex = ""
                        Return
                    Case ValidationTypes.DIGIT25
                        Me.Regex = ""
                        Return
                    Case ValidationTypes.Custom
                    Case Else
                        Return
                End Select
            End Set
        End Property

Example
sample      digit   remark
Hello My     8     not successful
Hello        5     not successful
1234567890  10     successful
12345678901 11     not successful should this fail
Hello My W  10     not successful
Hello My 1  10     not successful
Hello12345  10     not successful
Hello@2345  10     not successful





Please add to the question some examples where your regex is working and not working along with what you have tried. \d{1,10} will match from 1 to 10 digits, so there is something else going on... Also really focusing on the issue would help (that you have other validations that work is not really relevant to working out some regexes.

@Richard , sorry sir, I've updated in the example post

FYI: 1-10 digit string = ^[0-9]{1,10}$, etc.
